# Emails firing twice with scheduler class

Tags: apex, email-template, scheduled-apex

I am trying to send a HTML Email Template with an attached PDF, using this scheduler class. I receive two emails one with Attachment and the other is just the text without Attachment(not a text version).

```
global class pS implements Database.batchable<sObject> , Database.Stateful{

private EmailTemplate emailTemp;
global pS(){
    emailTemp = [Select Id From EmailTemplate Where Name = 'SP']; 
}

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    String query = 'Select Id, Lastname, Firstname, Email From Contact WHERE ((Account.RecordType.Id = \'01239000000N6dy\' AND Account.premier__c = False) OR (RecordType.Id = \'01239000000N6e1\' AND Account.Status__c = \'Processing\')) AND Account.Name != \'Test\' AND Email != null AND HasOptedOutOfEmail = False';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> scope){           

    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    for(Contact con : scope) {
         if(emailTemp != null && con.Email != null && con.Email != '') {
           Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
           email.setToAddresses(new List<String>{con.Email}); 
           email.setTargetObjectId(con.Id);                   
           email.setTemplateId(emailTemp.Id);
           email.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(true);        
           emails.add(email);                                      
        }          
    Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
    }                
}   
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
}
}
```

Can someone help me with this, thanks.

Comment: I don't see where you're attaching a file to the outgoing messages at all. Also, `true` is the default for `setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient()`, so you don't need to do that, and you don't need to add the target ID and also a To address for the same contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending emails inside for loop.

```
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    for(Contact con : scope) {
         if(emailTemp != null && con.Email != null && con.Email != '') {
           Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
           email.setToAddresses(new List<String>{con.Email}); 
           email.setTargetObjectId(con.Id);                   
           email.setTemplateId(emailTemp.Id);
           email.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(true);        
           emails.add(email);                                      
        }          
    Messaging.sendEmail(emails); ------> this needs to be below curly bracket.
    }
```

If your batch size is bigger than 1 this batch class would send multiple emails for same contacts.

Let's say your batch contains 3 contacts named A, B, C.

First you send email to A.
Then you send email to A and B.
Then you send email to A, B and C. Just move send.email line below curly bracket.

Also your code does not have attachment part.

Comment: Awesome @tugce! worked like a charm, thank you so much!
We are attaching the PDF manually to the email template, because it keeps changing every week.

Comment: Okay. Glad it helped!